# Formatting part of text in Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I would like to change the fontweight of part of some text I give to matplotlib's text command on a plot using matplotlib. For example, I would like the first word to be bold. Also, I would like to change the font weight and font to Times New Roman without affecting the rest of the labels, i.e. x-axis and y-axis labels.

Browsing the stack exchange, I came across the rc('text', usetex=True) command. When I use this, these changes affect the entire plot (i.e., the x-axis and y-axis labels as well). I would just like to format the text given to matplotlib's text command. Is there a way to do this?

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

randomNumber = []

for index in range(0, 1000):
    np.random.seed()
    randomNumber.append(np.random.normal(0, 1, 1)[0])

plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.hist(randomNumber, 12)
#plt.figure()
#plt.plot()
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
ax.text(-2, 150, '\\textbf{test} testing', fontsize=16, fontname='Times New Roman')
```

Comment: you can pass `usetex=True` as a kwarg to `text`

Comment: When I try to do this: `plt.text(-2, 150, r'\textbf{Some text}', fontsize=16, color='blue', fontname='Times New Roman', usetex=True)`, I get unknown property usetex. Have you had success with this?

Comment: That might be new in mpl1.5

Comment: That seemed to fix that issue, but I am not able to change the font from default to Times New Roman now using `fontname='Times New Roman'` as a kwarg. The fontsize does work though, and I can now make part of the text bold.

Comment: Hi, Do you fix it? How did you solve it